# JQuery keep tooltip in viewport

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am trying to keep a tooltip in viewport. The code seems to work except when the page is scrolled.

Can someone look at this?

```
<div class="test"></div>
<p><a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Cool tooltip with long name">Cool tooltip</a></p>
<p>or <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Another tooltip">Another tooltip</a></p>
<div class="test"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QvLwd/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you should change this line:

```
pos_top  = target.offset().top - tooltip.outerHeight() - 20 - $(window).scrollTop();
```

to:

```
pos_top  = target.offset().top - tooltip.outerHeight() - 20; // initial top relative to BODY
```

and this:

```
if( pos_top < 0 )
```

to:

```
if( pos_top < $(window).scrollTop() )
```

(and similar changes for pos_left)

It's because target.offset() gives you position relative to your BODY element and your BODY element's position is affected by the scroll (i.e. BODY expands above the top of the window when it is scrolled).

In other words: because you are adding tooltip element to the BODY, you should not adjust it's position by `$(window).scrollTop()` when calculating tooltip's position because it will be adjusted by it anyway (through it's parent's, i.e. BODY's, position). All you need to do, is check if tooltip's initial position is above the window, and move it down in this case - everything in BODY that has top coordinate `< $(window).scrollTop()` will be hidden (at least partially).

Comment: Thanks, I have adjusted top position now: http://jsfiddle.net/QvLwd/12/ But I am having trouble with left, it gets cut out.

Comment: You have a couple more bugs there: 1. `if( pos_top < $(window).scrollLeft() )` should be `if( pos_left < $(window).scrollLeft() )` 2. `pos_left = target.offset().left + target.outerWidth() / 2 - 20;` - this may still be outside the screen, why not do `pos_left = $(window).scrollLeft()`? 3. `if( pos_left + tooltip.outerWidth() > $( window ).width() )` - this is also wrong, should be `if( pos_left + tooltip.outerWidth() > $( window ).width() + $(window).scrollLeft())`

Comment: 4. `pos_left = target.offset().left - tooltip.outerWidth() + target.outerWidth() / 2 + 20;` should be `pos_left = $( window ).width() + $(window).scrollLeft() - tooltip.outerWidth();`

Comment: You should also use class="tooltip" (and ".tooltip" in css) because id should be unique.